# Get Column from .txt File using CSV.Reader in Python

Tags: python, csv

I've got a text file that looks like this:

```
162.8008    EXP  Set primary_image image=stimulus/Faces/face046.jpg
162.8008    EXP  Set secondary_image image=stimulus/Scenes/scene57.jpg
162.8008    EXP  Set primary_image opacity=1.0
162.8008    EXP  Set secondary_image opacity=0.0
162.8008    EXP  Set stimulus_instr text=press for repeated faces
```

And I've read it in like this:

```
log_data = []

with open('../filename.log.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
        log_data.append(row)
```

I want to access JUST that third column, right now when I say:

```
print log_data[2][:]
```

I'm returned all of a single row, like:

```
['8.8093', 'EXP', 'Started presenting text_2']
```

And when I switched and instead do:

```
print log_data[:][2]
```

I get the same exact result! I've been trying to convert it to an array with numpy and using a .split() function with no luck. Any expertise would be greatly appreciated - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `numpy`, the following should be OK

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

dat = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
print dat[:,2]
```

Result: `['Set' 'Set' 'Set' 'Set' 'Set']`

This post [How to use numpy.genfromtxt when first column is string and the remaining columns are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319969/how-to-use-numpy-genfromtxt-when-first-column-is-string-and-the-remaining-column) might be of some help.

Comment: I tried this, also using a header/footer skipper. When I try print log_data[:,2] I get an "IndexError: invalid index"

Comment: Nevermind - this worked I forgot the dtype=str. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
print [row[2] for row in log_data]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent of writing

```
n = len(log_data[2] - 1
print log_data[2][0:n]
```

That is, you are telling it to print every element within row 2. If you want to access only column 3 of row then you need to use

```
print log_data[2][3]
```

If you want to loop over the data

```
for row in log_data:
  # process row
  for col in row:
    # process each column
```

The reverse case that you mention, log_data[:][2], is printing row 2 of the slice which is the equivalent of

```
n = len(log_data) - 1
print log_data[0:n][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is not needed, and for the given data set I don't see why you would choose to use it.

```
def get_column(n, data):
    return [row[n] for row in data]

print(get_column(2, log_data))  # => ["Set", "Set", "Set", ...]
```