# Numpy: genfromtxt forming tuples

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my menu.csv:

```
Item,Price
Curry Rice,3.5
Pork Chop,6
Seafood Soup,5
Salad,2.8
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
menu_items = np.genfromtxt("menu.csv", delimiter=',',names=True)
print(menu_items)
```

What I get:

```
[(nan, 3.5) (nan, 6.2) (nan, 3. ) (nan, 2.8)]
```

When I use dtype=None:

```
[(b'Curry Rice', 3.5) (b'Pork Chop', 6.2) (b'Seafood Soup', 3. )
 (b'Salad', 2.8)]
```

What I want:

```
[(Curry Rice, 3.5) (Pork Chop, 6.2) (Seafood Soup, 3. ) (Salad, 2.8)]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use numpy.genfromtxt when first column is string and the remaining columns are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319969/how-to-use-numpy-genfromtxt-when-first-column-is-string-and-the-remaining-column)

Comment: The 'b' indicates bytestring values, a `S` dtype.  In Py3 `unicode` is the standard string type.  Try adding `encoding=None` to your `genfromtxt` call

Answer (score 1):

With your sample file:

```
In [349]: cat stack58789967.txt                                                 
Item,Price
Curry Rice,3.5
Pork Chop,6
Seafood Soup,5
Salad,2.8

In [350]: np.genfromtxt('stack58789967.txt',delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None)                                                                     
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode 
   strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the 
   encoding, use None for the system default.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[350]: 
array([(b'Curry Rice', 3.5), (b'Pork Chop', 6. ), (b'Seafood Soup', 5. ),
       (b'Salad', 2.8)], dtype=[('Item', 'S12'), ('Price', '<f8')])

In [351]: np.genfromtxt('stack58789967.txt',delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None, encoding=None)                                                      
Out[351]: 
array([('Curry Rice', 3.5), ('Pork Chop', 6. ), ('Seafood Soup', 5. ),
       ('Salad', 2.8)], dtype=[('Item', '<U12'), ('Price', '<f8')])
```

'S12' is bytestring dtype, one byte per character.  This is the Py2 norm.  'U12' is unicode dtype, 4 bytes per character.  This is the Py3 norm.

The 'tuples' here mark the records of a structured array.

The array is 1d, and fields are accessed by name:

```
In [352]: _.shape                                                               
Out[352]: (4,)
In [353]: __['Item']                                                            
Out[353]: array(['Curry Rice', 'Pork Chop', 'Seafood Soup', 'Salad'], dtype='<U12')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

I think your question looks very similar to [How to use numpy.genfromtxt when first column is string and the remaining columns are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319969/how-to-use-numpy-genfromtxt-when-first-column-is-string-and-the-remaining-column) . And it looks extensively answered. Have a look there and also check the `dtype` option for `np.genfromtxt` in the python [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) assumes that the data-type of each column is a float. You can ask it to try and guess the data-type of each column by passing it the keyword argument `dtype=None`.

```py
menu_items = np.genfromtxt("menu.csv", delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=None)
```

Comment: Hi, when I use dtype=None, I have b' in front of the menu items (I edited the page for clarification)